# List all the jobs in Beanstalkd

Tags: queue, beanstalkd, pheanstalk

We have beanstalkd running in our server. All our application records are stored in beanstalk before they are written into the mysql tables. Now few items got stuck inside this beanstalk queue. They are not being written into the database. So I would like to fetch all the items which are stuck in this Queue so that we can analyse further to see if they are corrupt entries. I could not find any way to list all the items from beanstalkd. Is there any way I can do it?

Comment: I don't think there's anything built in. When I've needed this, I just wrote a simple PHP script that consumes everything in the queue and displays it.

Comment: Thanks Barmar for responding this. I am trying to write a script. Could you please give me a clue as how to do this.

Comment: You use the same functions as in your normal script that fetches from the queue and adds to the database. Just change it to print the data instead of  sending to the DB.